# Meaning "versd'ber."

Tags: german-to-english

In the manufacturing and production sense what does the second item listed below mean in German and what is its translation to English ?

> 1. gefertigt
> 2. versd'ber.
> 3. abgesandt

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Just guessing, but in this context it might possibly be an abbreviation of "versandbereit" (ready for shipment)

Update: Now a scan of the original has been posted: it **is** an abbreviation of "versandbereit"

Answer (score 1):

A word *verad'ber* doesn't exist in the German language neither any word remotely similar!

Given the context the word could be *verarbeitet* (processed).

Thus, you have:

> 1. produced
> 2. processed
> 3. shipped

*Addendum:*

After addition of the scanned image, I see "versd'ber." instead of "verad'ber." Therefore, I think that PiedPiper is right with his guess. It's:

> versd'ber. = versandbereit --> ready for shipment

Comment: danke schön everyone !!!